# Canvas - это полная замена SVG?

Tags: svg, canvas

Хотел бы узнать, canvas может полностью заменить технологию SVG? То есть делать всё то, что умеет SVG?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, canvas не может полностью или даже частично заменить технологию SVG. Для любого дочернего объекта SVG можно повесить обработчик событий JavaScript, а для Canvas нельзя. Canvas это растровая графика, а SVG - векторная. И таких отличий еще не мало...

Comment: единственное что хотел бы уточнить в сфере построения диаграмм и графиков canvas будет достаточно или всё же придется изучать SVG?

Comment: Для диаграмм и графиков Canvas будет достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Для диаграмм и графиков лучше всего подходит SVG, а Canvas лучше использовать для динамичной переработки графической информации или изменения растровых изображений.